# Количество таблиц в базе MySQL влияет на скорость базы и следовательно скорости сайта?

Tags: php, mysql

Когда много инфы в базе имеет смысл много таблиц в ней создавать и хранить все в разных местах для распределения нагрузки на базу... чтобы сайт справлялся с нагрузками?

Comment: Бессмысленная трата времени и человеко-часов разработчика. Что-бы сайт справлялся с нагрузками всего-то нужен нормальный код, не более.

Уж если хотите оптимизировать скорость работы SQL СУБД - реализуйте серверную логику так, что-бы выборка из БД происходило из временной таблицы с ENGINE=MEMORY(соответственно нужно организовать cron скрипт который проверял бы существование этой таблицы с определенным промежутком времени и синхронизировать crud операции статической таблицы с временной). Но не думаю что у вас так много информации что вам это нужно.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! да, у меня не слишком много информации! у меня многие ко многим.. поэтому несколько таблиц в базе, т.к. я слышал если сделать все в одной - то это будет перегруз системы.. лучше перераспределить нагрузку на несколько таблиц(я новичок в php, может не так что то понял)...

Comment: Выборка из одной таблицы работает быстрее выборки из многих. Другое дело что разруливать хранение и синхронизацию данных в таких таблицах довольно геморройно. Поддерживать и развивать код становиться намного сложнее. Вообщем, по хорошему, делается это только в особо запущенных случаях (когда речь идет о гигах данных либо десятках таблиц)

Вообщем - не тратьте своего времени, если хотите что-бы код работал быстрее лучше займитесь оптимизацией оного.

Comment: У меня 6 таблиц: в одной категории, в другой - статьи... потом теги.. потом две таблицы связей... примерно такая структура.. ну у меня не будет супер посещаемый сайт я думаю... У меня такой вопрос, от пары тысячи посетителей в день он же не будет перегружаться?

Comment: Конечно нет, можете не беспокоиться.

Comment: Спасибо, AlexWindHope! Вы меня успокоили. И последний вопрос, если я вас еще не утомил... как вы поняли у меня на сайте есть категории статей, сами статьи и теги к каждой статье...я вижу вы опытный пользователь как бы вы на моем месте сформировали структуру базы данных.. сколько бы таблиц сделали.. ну так кратко.. общую концепцию можете сказать.. это мне так на будущее, просто хочется знать как делают подобные проекты грамотные программисты..  хочу развиваться))) ны вы меня понимаете)))

Comment: Это не для комментария, если вы хотите чтобы вам ответили на этот вопрос - задавайте новый.

Comment: Таблиц должно быть столько, чтобы вся схема находилась не ниже, чем в 3-ей НФ, а еще лучше - в БК НФ. Что касается конечной денормализированной таблицы, то лучше заменить ее представлением. Тогда отпадут трудности, описанные уважаемым @AlexWindHope.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не понял что такое (3-ей НФ, а еще лучше - в БК НФ.)

Comment: НФ - нормальная форма. БК - НФ Бойса-Кодда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Господа развели холивар!
Далее скромное ИМХО:
 1. Таблицы должны быть нормализованы (связи многое-ко-многим, в частности)
 2. Не имеет значение количество таблиц! Главное - правильные запросы и индексы!

Comment: п.с. количество таблиц не влияет! Всё зависит от грамотности кода и связей в них!

Comment: @kemerov4anin - да ну?

Ок, допустим у вас запрос в котором джойняться 10 таблиц, а у меня 1 таблица где просто лежит вся необходимая информация. Как думаете чей запрос будет быстрее?

Таблицы должны быть нормализованы в процессе разработки (без вариантов), но иногда приходиться делать денормализация (зачастую страшную, грязную и брутальную) во имя производительности, это - факт

Comment: Какой бы грамотной связь не была это никогда не будет быстрее чем ее отсутствие

Comment: Лимит комментов, 2 @BuilderC - представление это всего-лишь обвертка, представление работает быстрее простых джойнов, но не быстрее денормализованной статической таблицы.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, абсолютно согласен с Вами. Представление быстрее запросов потому, что уже разобрано и скомпилировано. Ускорить работу представления может разумная индексация.